# Haskell on Travis CI fails, passes locally

Tags: haskell, cabal, travis-ci

https://travis-ci.org/Fresheyeball/fbatch

```
Preprocessing library monad-parallel-0.5...
Control/Monad/Parallel.hs:67:8:
    Could not find module `Control.Monad.Identity'
    It is a member of the hidden package `mtl-2.2.1'.
    Perhaps you need to add `mtl' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
monad-parallel-0.5 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I am new to haskell, and just can't seem to get past this. I've tinkered with my `.cabal` file all I can, and the sub dependency fails on Travis every time.

Please help.

Comment: Bit strange that it tries such an old version of `monad-parallel`... 0.5 is evidently broken. What happens if you push that dependency up to `>= 0.7` (which properly imports `Control.Monad.Trans.Identity`)?

Comment: ok. I'll try that. But more importantly. I want to know how you went about figuring that out.

Comment: Quite simple: I looked up [the source of `Control.Monad.Parallel`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-parallel-0.7.1.2/docs/src/Control-Monad-Parallel.html), where the URL shows it's version 0.7.1.2 of the package. I noticed the import list does not have `Control.Monad.Identity` in it, which version 0.5 has and causes your error message.

Comment: That did it. Please post it as an answer along with how you looked it up, and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a build fails while resolving a dependency, it's worth having a look a what version of that package gets installed. Normally, cabal should default to the most recent possible, which if well-maintained should install fine. Older versions do of course often mean trouble, if some dependency of theirs has now a newer, incompatible version installed.

In your case, cabal tried to install the somewhat ancient `monad-parallel-0.5`, which imports a module that doesn't exist in `transformers` (namely `Control.Monad.Identity`). The more recent version `0.7.1.2` does not try this and thus builds successfully. You can force such a recent install by giving a lower bound to the dependency in your `.cabal` file, in this case `monad-parallel >= 0.7`.